# is it possible to generate production cloudflare turnstile key in test environment

Tags: http, cloudflare-turnstile

I add the cloudflare turnstile bot detection into my website, and I also have the automate test in test environment.

Now I am facing a issue that some feature must test in production environment. the test environment could not emulate the production parameters. is it possible to generate the production cloudflare turnstile key in test environment? For example, generate the cloudflare turnstile key in `test.example.com` that could used in `prod.example.com`.